# EC2 instance - No space left on device

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage

I am trying to install Anaconda on my EC2 instance.

After installing it with the bash command:
[image]

At some point the process stops and I get the message: 'No space left on device'.

To understand I entered the following commands:

[image]

[image]

What I do not understand is that I am supposed to have 8Gb on an EBS volume linked to my EC2.

Why do I only see 4Gb when entering the free command?

Also not sure about the difference between df -h & free commands.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The root volume is full. `Avail: 0`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for system administration questions, even when system problems happen when you install programming tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you're out of disk space.  As you can see in the first screenshot, `/dev/xvda1` is at 100% usage.  You need to create a instance that has more disk space.  The O/S likely takes ~1GB of that space so plan accordingly.  Allocate at least 20GB for most things, more if you expect to have a large amount of disk in use.

The `df` command shows you disk space usage.  The `free` command shows you memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You are running out of disk space on your root volume, it is where the OS resides. Its always advisable to use a separate disk for your applications. Below mentioned is the description of the commands you used

1. `df -h` : shows the disk usage for every partition.
2. `free -m` shows the memory usage of your machine.

In this case you should first cleanup the space used on your / volume (This can be your application which you deployed). It will free up the space on the root volume and let your OS function properly.

Post this you can create a separate EBS volume of a size greater than or equal to 8 GB and mount it on your instance. This volume should be used to deploy your application. This will ensure that your application and OS are on separate disks and will prevent affecting each other in case of any issues at the OS or Application level in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`free -m` shows you the amount of free memory (RAM), not the amount of hard disk. Your solution would be to get a storage volume from AWS and mount that to your EC2 instance.